# Cannot use data binding with layout files from television modules after updating to gradle 3.2.0

Tags: android, data-binding, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I have a shared module and a module for a TV.  After updating to gradle plugin `3.2.0` from `3.0.0`, more parts of the app, specifically classes which aren't inherited from shared module, are crashing when opened on TV due to this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.package.tv.databinding.FragmentDialogGenericBindingImpl cannot be cast to 
com.package.shared.databinding.FragmentDialogGenericBinding at 
com.package.shared.dialog.GenericDialog.onCreateView(GenericDialog.java:48)
```

So in this specific case I have:

- A shared layout file in shared module in layout directory, called `fragment_dialog_generic.xml`
- A layout file in tv module in layout-television directory, called `fragment_dialog_generic.xml`
- A GenericDialog class which inside `onCreateView` line 48 has:

  ```
   FragmentDialogGenericBinding dialog = 
   DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_dialog_generic, container, false);`
  ```

Until the update the binding was generating alright, now for some reason it cannot cast to `FragmentDialogGenericBinding`.

In both shared(library) module and television module I have data binding enabled, dagger `2.16`, support library `26.1.0`.

When updating from gradle plugin `3.0.0` to `3.2.0` I had to update the following libraries:

- kotlin from `1.2.20` to `1.2.51`
- classpath `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.2` to `1.25.4`
- `gradle-4.2.1-all.zip` to `gradle-4.6-all.zip`

Does anyone know how could it get to a state where layout from television cannot be used over the default layout files?

Comment: With data binding, I would not use the same layout resource ID (`fragment_dialog_generic`) in two different modules. You might have better luck using the `inflate()` on `FragmentDialogGenericBinding`, to try to force it to use the correct class.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. This should act same as if I was using same file names inside the shared module for different layouts(layout and layout-land for example). The app picks the right layout file based on current state. Also, please see the question again, I've update it and found out the issue is because of gradle plugin 3.0.0 update to 3.2.0

Comment: "This should act same as if I was using same file names inside the shared module for different layouts" -- the binding class is generated based on the package name of the module. If you have the same layout resource name in two separate modules, I would expect you to get two separate binding classes... which is exactly what is happening, based on your question.

Comment: Ok, then how was it working until now with gradle plugin 3.0.0? It would become really confusing to have a different layout name just because it's in a different package. If another module has layout-land and shared module doesn't then it has to be ok for the module to have the same name for layout-land, and use the default layout from shared module on portrait. It would obviously crash if I would put same layout name inside `layout` folder. Resource folders are combined in the end anyway, and the right one has to be picked and always was getting picked.

Comment: "how was it working until now with gradle plugin 3.0.0?" -- I have no idea. "Resource folders are combined in the end anyway" -- data binding code generation is not. Two modules with the same layout resource ID result in two identically-named binding classes, each in its own package, just as you are seeing. Again, I would try calling `inflate()` on the desired edition of `FragmentDialogGenericBinding`, rather than assuming that `DataBindingUtil` is going to guess which of the two classes that you want.

Comment: Thank you for further explanation. I honestly don't see how it would work with data binding for multiple views, for setting variables and for getting an instance of layout elements from that view. Even though the layout from TV and from the shared module would require same variables to be set, the place and styles for those elements would differ. So how would I further solve this problem if I'd inflate the view the old way? I wouldn't want to have this GenericDialog inside TV module as well; that would be too much to maintain.

Comment: So currently I'm creating a generic `ViewDataBinding` and setting the variables using BR rather than setters. Not able to access views from binding of course, since it crashes if I try to cast it. While that solves the crash, it doesn't fully solve the problem: I can't fallback to old way of findViewById long term. Or I'd have to create a class for every view where it looks different on TV which seems to be overkill.